# Use icon and text as input placeholder

Tags: javascript, html, css, placeholder, emoji

I'm trying to use an icon with text as a placeholder of text input field, I tried to copy and paste an Icon from Emoji(http://getemoji.com/) icons, but it doesn't work. I have an idea for this case by using an image icon using css and add javascript code to hide it on focus, but you may have another solution be easier.

Comment: May be worth noting that some emojis will render in color, and others won't. e.g. in my case (using Inter var), `☺️` rendered in black & white, but most other smiley emojis rendered in color.

Answer (score 1):

give you here is the solution **css**

try this code   [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RGrc3/1/)

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="name" placeholder=" some text">
```

**CSS**

```
    input {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    font-size:2em;
    border: 1px solid #767676;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 331px;
    height: 44px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}
:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {color: transparent}
:focus::-moz-placeholder          {color: transparent}
:focus:-moz-placeholder           {color: transparent}
:focus:-ms-input-placeholder      {color: transparent}
```

Comment: doesn't work, appears like square .. is there specific encode for it ?

Comment: try <p class="emoji" style="font-size:3.5em">




☺




































































</p>

Comment: or search for special characters such as here such &#8364;